# What is this scrolling called used on http://www.apple.com/uk/mac-pro/

Tags: html, css

This is just a simple short question but all i would like to know is, 
What is this scrolling called used on http://www.apple.com/uk/mac-pro/ ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Scrolling? Or fading? Dude, waaaatt?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the design of a website that will almost certainly change in the future, rendering the question incomprehensible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The animation is actually created in a movie clip (49 seconds long mp4), which plays to a certain point when the user scrolls down the page.

You can read more about how this site was put together in my deconstruction:

[Apple Mac Pro page deconstructed](http://ihatetomatoes.net/apple-mac-pro-page-deconstructed/)

Comment: Excellent deconstruction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's called parallax scrolling, but with a lot of modifications if we talk about mac-pro website.

The nice library for it is [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr).